# Se pueden pasar variable de bash a php

Tags: php, bash, variables

Tengo una duda que no se si es que no se puede o que no se como se hace.
Si tengo este código **php:**

```
<?php
$salida = shell_exec('bash prueba.sh');
echo "<pre>$salida</pre>";
exit;
?>
```

y este en **bash:**

```
#!/bin/bash
patch="una_ruta_cualquiera"

lista=$(ls -lt $patch | grep ^d | awk '{print $9}')
for carpeta in $lista; do
    #echo $carpeta
    listar=$(ls -l $patch/$carpeta | grep -v ^d | awk '{print $9}')
    for archivos in $listar; do
        echo "$carpeta/$archivos"
    done
done
```

Puedo hacerlo de alguna manera en la que el resultado (`echo "$carpeta/$archivos"`) llegase al php de forma que fuese una **$variable** en **php** y pudise trabajar con ella?

Comment: En la variable `$salida` de `PHP` deberías estar obteniendo todo lo que se imprimió en la salida (`echo`) el script `prueba.sh`, o no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El valor que obtienes en la variable `$salida` puedes pasarlo a array a partir de un comodín que concatenes en el `echo` que imprimes en el bash, así podrás separar la línea.

En el bash :

```
#!/bin/bash
patch="una_ruta_cualquiera"

lista=$(ls -lt $patch | grep ^d | awk '{print $9}')
for carpeta in $lista; do
    #echo $carpeta
    listar=$(ls -l $patch/$carpeta | grep -v ^d | awk '{print $9}')
    for archivos in $listar; do
        echo "$carpeta/$archivo-\$-"
    done
done
```

En el php:

```
$salida .= shell_exec('bash prueba.sh');
$a_salida = explode("-$-",$salida);

foreach ($a_salida as $valor) {
    echo $valor."<br />";
}
```

**corregido**

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Se podria pasar mas de una variable? o quedarian todas dentro del mismo array?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo aria en tu caso seria guardar el valor de la variable de bash en un archivo y luego desde el php con un **fopen** leeria el archivo y le pasaría el valor a una variable de php.

Comment: La idea me gusta, pero... Puedo hacer que cada linea de texto sea una variable? y como, GRACIAS!

Comment: @juan en ese caso yo te recomiendo que en bash cada vez que vallas a guardar hagas un salto de linea y que en cada linea tambien valla el nombre de la variable. Algo asi:

Comment: **$variable:valordelavariable**  Luego con el php hacer un readlines y eso te devuelve un array que recorrerías con un for y ahora cada vez que vas recorriendo el for la variable temporal te da un string que luego le aplicas un **split(":")** y asi separas el nombre de la variable con el valor, eso te devuelve un array y asi el dato[0] seria el nombre de la variable que te sirve para saber que datos tiene, sera una guia. dato[1] tendrá el valor de la variable y ese lo metes en una variable php que fue lo que te dije anteriormente.

Comment: Intente hacer lo que me has comentado, pero en algún punto no te seguí. como debo tratar el contenido para pasarlo al **array**. yo probé con pasarlo de esta manera `$salida=split(":",$linia)`. No se si me podrías explicar un poco mejor el proceso o alguna cosa. Pero gracias por la idea!